# How can I transform the str to Unicode?

Tags: string, python-3.x, unicode, python-3.5

The content in my file is like:

`This is a Japanese character: \u3046`

And I want to transfer the above string into this form:

`This is a Japanese character:  unicodeValue_3046|unidecoded_u`

Here is my code:

```
def my_repl(match):
   return ' unicodeValue_' + match.group('uni')[2:] + '|unidecoded_' +unidecode(match.group('uni'))

re.sub(pattern=r'(?P<uni>\\u[a-f0-9]{4})', repl=my_repl, string=open('ja.txt', 'r').readline())
```

What I get is not what I expected:

```
Out[207]: u'This is a Japanese character:  unicodeValue_3046|unidecoded_\\u3046 '
```

After I write it to the file:

```
opt = re.sub(pattern=r'(?P<uni>\\u[a-f0-9]{4})', repl=my_repl, string=open('ja.txt', 'r').readline())
codecs.open('op', 'w', 'utf-8').write(opt)
```

What I see is this:
`This is a Japanese character:  unicodeValue_3046|unidecoded_\u3046`

Then the unidecode doesn't work, it just outputs what is given.

I know that: `unidecode(u'\u3046')` and `unidecode('\u3046')` are 'u', but in my case it differs.

How can I work it out?

Comment: You are getting exactly what you wanted, you just need to understand what you are looking for.

Comment: As an aside, it's 2018, Python 2 should be dead already according to the original end-of-life plans. It got an extension and will be kept in terminal care until 2020; but really, in this day and age, you should be planning to transition to Python 3 or ideally already be in that process.

Comment: @tripleee You are right. The matter disappears in Python3.

Comment: @tripleee It still is confusing. Please help me out. Thank you.

Comment: `print` the result from `re.sub` and you will see its `__str__` representation instead of its `__repr__`.  This is a very common FAQ.

Comment: @tripleee Please see my updates.

Comment: `unidecode` is not a defined function name; please try to update your question into a [mcve]. Avoiding the input file and using `string='This is a Japanese character: \\u3046'` makes this simpler for others to replicate.

Comment: Maybe also look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38385089/how-to-convert-repr-into-encoded-string to get the data in correctly in the first place. (There's an answer which suggests `open(..., encoding='unicode_escape')` in particular.)