# use GPT3.5 to translate articles from English to Traditional Chinese

Tags: python, openai-api

it's so odd.
when i call the funciton to translate the contents to Traditional Chinese
openai gives me a bunch of unicodes, that i dont even understand

BUT, if i use playground on openai website to translate to Traditional Chinese, it works fine.

```
title = "U.S. Treasury Says DeFi Threatens National Security; MacOS Mystery Over Hidden Bitcoin White Paper"

completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
model="gpt-4",
messages=[
    {"role": "system", "content": "you are a blockchain expert and financial trader"},
    {"role": "user", "content": f"translate this content {n} to Traditional Chinese"},
]
)
result = completion.choices[0].message
print(result)
```

when i ask openai to translate to French or Swedish or others languange
it works perfectly fine!

by the way, it works with GPT-3-turbo, but not GPT-3.5 and 4

have no idea what's wrong, please help

Comment: How do you test this? Maybe problem is just printing in your console (encoding/code-page issues)? Can you show example output?

Comment: output :  "content": "\u8fd9\u573a\"\u5bf9\u52a0\u5bc6\u7684\u6218\u4e89\"\u662f\u4e00\u573a\u72ec\u7279\u7684\u7f8e\u56fd\u6218\u4e89\u5417\uff1f"

Comment: I pasted that to my python cosole `a = "\u8fd9\u573a\"\u5bf9\u52a0\u5bc6\u7684\u6218\u4e89\"\u662f\u4e00\u573a\u72ec\u7279\u7684\u7f8e\u56fd\u6218\u4e89\u5417\uff1f"` and printed `a` outcome is correct: `这场"对加密的战争"是一场独特的美国战争吗？`. So I'm right: everything works, your console is badly configured or you are viewing this data in bad way.

Comment: do you mean i need to do some settings on console so that can print the Chinese words? thank you for your reply

Comment: Looks like encoding on your output device is unable to show those characters so fallback kicks in (escape sequence for Unicode). So API works problem is presenting data. Try run this in python console not from system console.

Comment: :( same, i always run with python console, and that's even weird if I use "text-davinci-003" model, the output print Chinese words perfectly

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38401636/1387438